# Ruby Migration Error: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

Using Rails 4.2.6, Ruby 2.0.0, OSX 10.11

I'm trying to run the rails server. Before that, I run "rake db:migrate", then I get the following error:

> rake aborted!
>   StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
>   undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

I'm quite new on Ruby. Can someone explain the error and how to solve it?

Thank you!

Comment: can you please add some more logs?

Comment: Please post the trace and also the migration in which you are getting error

Comment: Please post your migration code in which you are getting this issue, or if you don't want to share code then please put that migration file out side the db/migrate directory of your application and run migration again and if you get any other issue while running migration in any other migration file then please do the same thing for this.

After run migration put all these files again in your db/migrate folder and then run your migration again.

I think it will resolve your issue.

Comment: This error means you are trying to call `.id` on an Object which is `nil`.

Comment: If you want debugging help you need to provide a minimal example of the code where the error is occurring. Otherwise there is nothing we can do to help you.

Comment: I fixed this problem. Just remove .id in the migration file that causes this error. Thank you all. (It might be some syntax change on ruby)

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this as well. The answer above wasn't very helpful in this case because so much of running the migration is meta programed in Active Record.

For me, the issue was that I had written a migration like this:

```
create_table :user_table do |t|
  t.id :reference_table_id
end
```

I fixed it by changing the middle line to `t.integer` instead because `id` is not a column type.

Without seeing your migration I cannot be sure this will solve your issue, but it's what worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the stack trace of the error (the stuff on the terminal after the error is displayed)

You should see a pointer to the line of code where the error is. It'll probably be something like `x.id` where x is the nil value